# I am making an Atari Breakout clone & I am wondering how to tell if the ball hits a certain side of a block

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, canvas

I have gotten the part where when the ball collides with the block it deletes the block, but I am also wanting to tell if the ball hits the top or bottom or left or right of the block and bounce accordingly. I have attempted it, but it's not working quite right. It just freaks out jumping around. I have deleted that portion from the code below as it does not work. Can anyone help me out with this problem? Maybe give an example or tell me how it would work?

```
<canvas id="can" height="500" width="1000"></canvas>


        var c = document.getElementById("can");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        var blocks= [];
        var paddle = {x:450,y:480,h:10,w:100};
        var ball = {r:7,x:500,y:469};
        var rows=[0,1,2,3,4];
        var px = paddle.x, py = paddle.y;
        var pxv=0;
        var by = ball.y, bx = ball.x;
        var bxv = -1.5, byv = -1.5;


        function Block(h,w,x,y,c) {
            this.h = h;
            this.w = w;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.c = c;
        }
        for(var i =0, len=rows.length;i<len;i++){
            for(var j=0; j<20;j++) {
            blocks.push(new Block(20,50,j*50,i*20,rows[i]))
        }
        }
        document.addEventListener("keydown",keyPush);
        document.addEventListener("keyup",keyRelease);
        function keyRelease(evt) {
            switch(evt.keyCode) {
                case 37: 
                    pxv=0;
                    break;
                case 39: 
                    pxv=0;
                    break;
            }
        }
        function keyPush(evt) {
            switch(evt.keyCode) {
                case 37: 
                    pxv=-5;
                    break;
                case 39: 
                    pxv=5
                    break;
            }
        }
        function AABBIntersect(ax, ay, aw, ah, bx, by, bw, bh) {
            return ax < bx+bw && bx < ax+aw && ay < by+bh && by < ay+ah;
        };
        function draw(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,1000,500)
        bx+=bxv;
        by+=byv;
        px+=pxv;

        if(px > 900) {
            px = 900;
        }
        else if(px < 0) {
            px = 0;
        }
        for(var i = 0, len=blocks.length;i<len;i++) {
            var bl = blocks[i];
            if(AABBIntersect(bx,by,ball.r,ball.r,bl.x,bl.y,bl.w,bl.h)) {
                blocks.splice(i,1);
                i--;
                len--;
            }
        }
        if(bx < 0) {
            bxv = bxv*-1;
        }
        if(bx > 1000) {
            bxv = bxv*-1;
        }
        ctx.fillStyle = "#ff4b38"
        ctx.fillRect(px,py,paddle.w,paddle.h);
        for(var i = 0, len=blocks.length; i<len; i++){

                if(blocks[i].c === 0) {
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#ff4b38"
                }
                else if(blocks[i].c === 1) {
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffba19"
                }
                else if(blocks[i].c === 2) {
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#fcee25"
                }
                else if(blocks[i].c === 3) {
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#26db02"
                }
                else if(blocks[i].c === 4) {
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#2d69ff"
                }
                  ctx.fillRect(blocks[i].x,blocks[i].y,blocks[i].w,blocks[i].h);
                  ctx.beginPath();
                  ctx.arc(bx,by,ball.r,0,2*Math.PI,false);
                  ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
                  ctx.fill();

        }
        }
        setInterval(draw,10);
```

Comment: Where is your collision detection? `AABBIntersect()`?

Comment: Yes. It is a function outside of the draw() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there are more ways to do it but this is how I would do it.

Inside your collision detection function you should have if-statements to detect if from the x or y side. You made need to tweak it as not sure if it will error later but the brunt of it all is like this:

```
function AABBIntersect(ax, ay, aw, ah, bx, by, bw, bh) {
    var bool = ax < bx + bw && bx < ax + aw && ay < by + bh && by < ay + ah;
    if(bool){
        if(ax == bx || ax == bx + bw){
            bxv *= -1;
            cl("x");
        }else{
            byv *= -1;
            cl("y");
        }
    }   

    return bool;
};
```

Your next issue is you have no paddle collision detection, so it will bounce back but it will go through your paddle. So you can do the following in your `draw()` function. I put it after your `if(bx > 1000)`:

```
if(bx >= px && bx <= px + paddle.w && by >= py && by <= py + paddle.h){
    byv *= -1;
}
```

I would also put your `setInterval` on a var so you can clear it when either all the blocks are gone or your ball goes below the paddle. Otherwise it's just going to go everywhere infinitely.